# Install Lineage on P3110 with Replicant

Tags: lineageos, samsung-galaxy-tab

I installed Replicant on my P3110 only to discover the wifi is not supported. So now I want to install Lineage instead.

Apparently Lineage is no longer officially support by Lineage, but I have been able to find lineage-14.1_espressowifi-7.1.2-20180131-1818.zip

If I use Replicant's bootloader and try to do `adb sideload lineage-14.1_espressowifi-7.1.2-20180131-1818.zip` the sideload completes, but fails on the device with `E: failed to verify whole-file signature`.

I am thinking that I may have to install `espresso-common_TWRP_3.2.2-0.img` but I have found no way to do that from the Replicant bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking that I may have to install espresso-common_TWRP_3.2.2-0.img but I have found no way to do that from the Replicant bootloader.

I think you are correct, I don't think you can flash a new bootloader with the Replicant bootloader, only update it.

You will have to flash with a computer:

1. Plug your device into a computer
2. Put your device into downloading mode
3. Flash TWRP for your device

And then use TWRP to flash the LineageOS ROM for your device.